# Variable repetition inside INSIDE LOOKBEHIND in Delphi Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, delphi, regex-lookarounds, delphi-10.3-rio

I assume that the Regex dialect used in Delphi's **System.RegularExpressions** is **PCRE**. (I use Delphi Rio 10.3.3)

RegexBuddy gives me a warning with this Regex (when using PCRE):

```
(?<!('.*))\{.*?\}
```

> The PCRE library does not support variable repetition inside
>   lookbehind

This is a sample data I am trying to match:

```
ThisString := ' ab{comment inside a string}yz ';
```

Is there any way to use variable repetition inside lookbehind in a Regex in Delphi Rio 10.3.3?

Comment: Your example should not match `{comment inside a string}` because there is a single before it, right?

Comment: @anubhava it should not match when **{comment inside a string}** is inside a string

Comment: This is just another misuse of RegEx to parse a language/markup where a parser should be used in the first place. Sadly this happens here on daily basis. How about `ThisString := 'a' + {comment outside of string} 'b';`

Comment: @PeterWolf In this example you mention, `{comment outside of string}` would be matched - no problem. BTW, I don't know any good Delphi Object Pascal parser which would solve the problem described above. Do you?

Comment: I'm still not sure whether you're trying to match all comments inside strings or outside. The point I was trying to make was that the comment can be outside of any string but still between two single quotes. As for parser [DelphiAST](https://github.com/RomanYankovsky/DelphiAST) looks good, but I haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: @user Yes there certainly is a Delphi parser that can handle that. Regex is the wrong tool.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan For my specific purpose, I need to extract all elements of a specific type (comments, strings, numbers, ...) from a Delphi .pas source file. I have tried DelphiAST: It looks good, but it seems it cannot get compiler directives. Do you know a Delphi source parser that would fit my purpose?

Comment: As DelphiAST doesn't currently support compiler directives, I've come up with this regex to extract all compiler directives: `\{\$.*?\}`

Comment: You use DelphiAST to obtain the comments, and then you parse those for the directives

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Comments obtained with DelphiAST do NOT contain the directives. Although directives from the regex point of view are a special case of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PCRE (and in Delphi which uses PCRE) you can use `\K` to work around the limitations of lookbehind.  The regex in your question can be rewritten like this:

```
(?m)(^|\G)[^'\v]*?\K\{.*?\}
```

RegexBuddy 4.10.0 fully supports Delphi 10.3.  There's no difference in the regex support between 10.3.0 and 10.3.3.

If you're trying to match strings and comments in Delphi, you're better of with a straightforward regex that matches them separately.  This regex has 3 separate alternatives to match a string, comment, or alternate comment:

```
(?<string>'[^'\v]*+')|(?<comment>\{[^}]*+\})|(?<altcomment>(?m)\(\*.*?\*\))
```

Write some Delphi code to iterate over the matches of this regex and process or skip the match as a string, comment, or alternate comment based on which of the 3 capturing groups matched.

Comment: I have extended your regex to include other comment types (also not being inside a string): `(?m)(^|\G)[^'\v]*?\K\{.*?\}|(^|\G)[^'\v]*?\K\(\*.*?\*\)`. Is there a way to simplify this? And how could I include double-slash comments too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs:

```
'[^']*{[^']*'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|{.*?}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gbl3V4/2)

---

If your regex flavour doesn't support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, you can use:

```
'[^'{}]*{[^'{}]*}[^'{}]*'|({.*?})
```

and test if group 1 exists.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Gbl3V4/1)

Comment: When I insert this in RegexBuddy (PCRE) it gives me an error indication with this error message: "Quantifiers must be preceded by a token that can be repeated"

Comment: @user1580348: I haven't a Delphi compiler to test. But it works in regex101.com (with PCRE flavour) as you can see in the provided link;

Comment: I have tested it in Delphi 10.3.3. It does not work with Delphi System.RegularExpressions.

Comment: @user1580348: Too bad because it's a PCRE feature. You could try [this](https://regex101.com/r/Gbl3V4/2) and test if you get the capture group #1 that exists only when `{ ... }` is not inside a string.

Comment: This regex matches the whole string between and including the single quotation marks. But it should NOT match if the part between {} is between the single quotation marks. https://i.imgur.com/34YS9O1.png

Comment: @user1580348: The group 1 contains only `{comment outside a string}`, `{comment inside a string}` will never in group 1.  Just test if you have (or not) the group 1. If that is not what you want, please, edit your question to make it clearer, with more test cases. May be it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1686). What are you trying to do finaly?